# How to update single row using multiple tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update, left-join

I have 3 tables like:

```
animals: id, code, address
dogs: id,code, address
cats: id,code, address
```

Animals contain both data from dogs and cats and some more.
Some rows from animals table have NULL address values, and I want to UPDATE it with cats and dogs address values like this:

```
UPDATE animals
SET address = coalesce(cats.address,dogs.address)
FROM dogs
left join cats on cats.id = dogs.id
```

But I not sure that JOIN will work fine there.
How can I combine address values from both cats and dogs tables?
OR I need to update it one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to phrase this:

```
update animals a
set address = coalesce(c.address, d.address)
from animals a1
left join dogs d on d.id = a1.id
left join cats c on c.id = a1.id
where a.id = a1.id
```

Depending on your actual set-up, it might be a good idea to ensure that there is at least one match in either of the tables:

```
update animals a
set address = coalesce(c.address, d.address)
from animals a1
left join dogs d on d.id = a1.id
left join cats c on c.id = a1.id
where a.id = a1.id and (d.id is not null or c.id is not null)
```

Comment: In case it's not clear for the original poster: the reason you want to have animals in the FROM is because in your original query, if the dogs table had no row for a particular animal ID, that row would not be updated, even if there was a cat row, because a LEFT join will only unconditionally emit rows from the left-side table. You can fix that by either using an FULL join, or by making the left-hand-side of the LEFT join be the original table, as GMB has done here (& I prefer this way over the FULL join too; it's simpler to read & understand).